# Ubuntu 18.10 boot process occasionally hangs

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.10

When I am booting Ubuntu 18.10 on my desktop, most of the times it boots as it should. But occasionally it is getting stuck. When I open the text mode of booting, I'm getting this:

[image: boot process with everything [OK]]

At that time, the HDD activity indicator remains turned off. I have to press the reset button of the PC to start the boot process again.

What could be the problem and how can I fix it?